# Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init

Tags: ubuntu

We recently powered off our web server to move it up a rack space and blow out any dust.

It was powered off properly and everything was checked to be seated properly before powering back up. Unfortunately now we are getting the following error:

```
Target file system does'nt have /sbin/init.
run-init: Permission Denied
[    2.669669] Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init!
```

This is ubuntu server 10.04 64bit on a lenovo thinkserver running raid1.

The raid controller says everything is normal on the volume.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is a production server.

Comment: Boot off a live-cd.  Mount the volumes and check to see if your filesystem is not trashed.  Check to see if init is present and valid.

Comment: parted magic sees it but cannot manipulate it because it is LVM2 PV. Ubuntu live cd says the resource is busy.

Comment: Try to activate the volume with vgchange -a y.  Then do an `lvdisplay`.  Your volume should be listed, so try to mount it.  `mount /dev/mapper/whatever /mnt`.

Comment: Rule number one: `never Never Never **Never** ***NEVER*** blow the dust out of the machine! It ALWAYS breaks something. Scientists have been trying to figure out why since the days of mechanical relay computers.`  (Rule number two: `Before you ignore rule number one, make sure you have known good, restore-tested backups!`)

Comment: I guess sometimes the dust is all that's holding the smoke inside the electrolytics.

Comment: Well put voretaq. We do have a very current backup, but the time it takes to restore from our backup system is horrendous, so I am trying to just repair it first.

Comment: We were able to finally get into the filesystem using `lvdisplay` mentioned above by Zoredache. It appears that many of the init and mount files have no permissions. We are working to restore the permissions to get it booted

Comment: We finally got things working again. Just for time sake, we did a blanket command on all the files missing their permissions. `find /mnt/foo/ -perm 000 -exec chmod 777 \{\}\;`

Zoredache, if you put in for an answer Ill mark it checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by `Zoredache` in commends